# With Google People API, grabbing privately set profile data?

Tags: android, google-people-api

I got my Android Application to successfully pull the user's profile via Google People API to get the Person object. I am also successful in grabbing the user's birthday and gender from that object. Though after testing with my own Gmail and switching my account's gender and/or birthday to private, I was getting no response back from the API calls.

I am wondering if there is any way to be able to pull this information even if the user sets it to private? If I do a verification submission to Google of my application with the request scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile to get the user's profile, will there be an option to request to be able to read private data as well if it gets approved? Or am I out of luck getting the privately set data for the user? (This is mainly just to help the user not have to worry about additional screens for entering in data).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by requesting non-public profile scopes.

More information here : https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#profile-scopes